# Display flattened list items with count of more items that fit in a div

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have few list items which I want to display in flattened order on my website.
For the items which do not fit on the same line, I am trying to show a count of 'how many more items' are available. Something like this for 8 items:

```
screen size 1:
==============================
item1, item2, item3   +5 items
==============================

screen size 2:
====================================================
item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6    +2 items
====================================================
```

the skeleton of code that I have now is:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <span ng-repeat="item in items | canFit">
    <span class="itemname">{{item}}</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" ngshow="n>0">
   <span>+{{n}} items</span>
</div>
```

I currently implemented using an algorithm to calculate the character count, but the font-size, padding, screen size may change in future and I am trying to have something which is more agnostic of this changes with less perf impact.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

ps: I am using angularjs with bootstrap grid to show the items 
span10:(item1, item2, item3), span2: (+5 items)

Comment: this may be impacted by font selection- not all fonts have characters of equal width, kerning, etc.

Comment: You can use css to fix width of each item in 100%.. For example if you want to display 5 items then put style="width:20%" .

Comment: You can use a monospaced ("fixed-width") font like `this`. The rest should be simple math (or trial and error)

Comment: @Anita- I do not want to fix the number of items I am showing. Based on screen size I need to calculate how many items could fit in a screen, and then show a count of how many couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your questions may be it will helps [`Angular Material Child Alignment`](https://material.angularjs.org/#/layout/alignment)

[image]